# Open a terminal with Python but keep it running

Tags: python, ubuntu, gnome-terminal, ice

I am developing a distributed app with zeroc and to start all the servers needed we have made a script.
One of the commands to be executed is `icegridregistry --Ice.Config=registry.conf` so in the scripts it appears as `os.system("gnome-terminal -- icegridregistry --Ice.Config=./iceflix/registry.conf")` and it works, but I need that terminal window being opened and active instead of being closed when the command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the --Ice.Nohup option.

Syntax: `Ice.Nohup=num`

> If num is set to a value larger than zero, the C++ classes Ice::Application and Ice::Service ignore SIGHUP (for UNIX) and CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT (for Windows). As a result, an application that sets Ice.Nohup continues to run if the user that started the application logs off. The default value for Ice::Application is 0, and the default value for Ice::Service is 1 (C++ only.)

As per [documentation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/andrew/scs/cs/oldfiles/15-494-sp09/dst/A/sw/Ice-3.1.1/doc/reference/x18239.html#AEN18460).

Comment: And `gnome-terminal` would not be needed at al, you can use `subprocess.run()`